# Errors with Highcharts/Highstock and React, unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to get highstocks to work with react following the guide at https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts, I have come up with the following so far, I imported the first 2 lines, with the export underneath the last import. In my render function, I have the options I would like, but I am receiving this error. Is there something I have missed?

[image]

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
import Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
Exporting(Highcharts);

        <div className="chart">
          Highcharts.chart('container', {
              chart: {
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                height: 400
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Bitcoin Chart'
            },

            scrollbar: {
              enabled: false
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
                color: 'black',
                data: this.props.data.all_price_values,
                type: 'area',
                threshold: null,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }],
            plotOptions: {
            series: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 700],
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#FF9900'],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                }
            }
            },

            responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                        maxWidth: 500
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        chart: {
                            height: 300
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: null
                        },
                        navigator: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
          });
        </div>
```

I am trying to achieve this with my react application http://jsfiddle.net/votfqnur/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write js code directly in `<div className="chart"></div>`. At least, you need wrap the js code with `{}`, like `<div className="chart">{JSON.stringify({a:1})}</div>`

You can render chart in `componentDidMount`, this is my simple demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/l7xol9n887

Comment: Ok this works, but I am not getting the slider underneath to adjust the data, and I don't want to download the data. I want the view to be exactly as is on the jsfiddle

EDIT: I was able to figure it out from here, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/whawker/react-jsx-highcharts

This version works, as explained:

```
import { withHighcharts, HighchartsChart, Chart, /* etc... */ } from 'react-jsx-highcharts';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';

const MyChart = () => (
  <HighchartsChart>
    <Chart />
    // etc
  </HighchartsChart>
);

export default withHighcharts(MyChart, Highcharts); // Injecting the Highcharts object
```